# Why there is discontinuity at Zenith in Spherical-coordinate system?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I tried to plot the following function in spherical-coordinate system :

$$ r(\phi,\theta)=\left(\frac{\sin\phi}{\phi}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\right)^2$$

(definition/references for spherical-coordinates are described) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Unique_coordinates)

I got the following graphs (viewed from different angles):

[image]
[image]
[image]

As we progress through the zenith i-e (0 rad,0 rad) towards point($\pi$,0+$\delta$), the graph is Discontinuous,(as it jumps from 1 to 0 instantly)

I am confused with such type of pattern. Is it CORRECT plot or something I am missing ??

Help with be highly appreciated !

Comment: Think about the behaviour of the function $\varphi$ on the sphere.

Comment: Longitude $0$ and longitude $2\pi$ are the same longitude. But
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\sin x}x=1\neq0=\frac{\sin2\pi}{2\pi}.$$ More generally: $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and $(r,\theta,\phi+2\pi)$ mean the same point, so you usually want your function to be periodic in $\phi$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just want to know  whether the equation $ r(\phi,\theta)=\left(\frac{\sin\phi}{\phi}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\right)^2$ and its spherical-plot (plotted above) are consistent or Not ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's slice this thing open and look at a cross-section to illustrate what's going on.  Slicing with the plane $\phi = \pi/2$, we get the polar equation
$$r(\theta) = \frac{4 \sin^2 \theta}{\pi \theta^2}$$

What does that look like?  Let's plot it:

[image: plot]

As you can see, it's a bunch of nested things.  You're just seeing one of the inside ones peeking out.

Comment: Above plot is wrong, in context of spherical- coordinate system. You plotted for all the angles of $\theta$ which are not allowed in spherical coordinate system i-e $\theta>\pi$. The true slice along $\phi=\pi/2$ and $\phi=-\pi/2$ is a Cardioid shape. And if you look closely at my 3D plot, this cardioid shape is obvious along our cut. Moreover, my question still remains unanswered, as I just want to know whether my 3D plot is correct or not in context of spherical coordinates?

Comment: It's not the case that by definition a spherical plot is only done for $(\theta, \phi)$ in that (or any particular) region.  If you want to plot on a particular region that's fine, but you need to specify the region explicitly.